# utf8mb4_unicode_ci против utf8mb4_general_ci в mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Имеется таблица с текcтовым полем:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    ...
    `name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    ...
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Пытаюсь перейти на кодировку utf8mb4_unicode_ci:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `table1` COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci', CONVERT TO CHARSET utf8mb4;
```

И получаю вот это:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    ...
    `name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    ...
) COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Т.е. для тектового поле кодировка utf8mb4_general_ci, а для таблицы utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
Почему так происходит? Как привести все тектовые поля к кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

В настройках mySQL:

```
[server]
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character_set_server=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4.

[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
...


SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

mySQL 5.7.33

Также возможно ли изменить collation_connection по умолчанию для клиентов mySQL в ее конфиге?

Comment: Предварительная команда SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci в клиенте не помогает решить проблему с кодировкой полей таблицы.

Comment: *Почему так происходит?* Система приоритетов. Если установлены характеристики поля - применяются они. Если нет - применяются характеристики таблицы. Если тоже не установлено - применяются характеристики БД, которые установлены всегда. *Как привести все тектовые поля к кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci?* Явно установить COLLATE для поля соответствующим ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Возможно ли сменить collation_connection по умолчанию с utf8mb4_general_ci на utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Comment: *Возможно ли сменить collation_connection по умолчанию с utf8mb4_general_ci на utf8mb4_unicode_ci?* Легко. Задайте требуемое значение в файле конфигурации сервера или строке запуска его службы. Хуже, но тоже можно - настройки параметров соединения в файле конфигурации сервера, строке запуска клиента, настройки (в т.ч. дополнительные команды при подключении) коннектора.